# PostgreSQL: Select where timestamp is empty

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that looks like the following:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp = NULL;`

The timestamp column is a timestamp with time zone data type (second type in [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE) table). This is in PostgreSQL 8.4.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to only select rows that have not had a timestamp inserted. When I look at the data in pgAdmin the field is empty and shows no value. I've tried where timestamp = `NULL`, `'EPOCH'` (which you would think would be the default value), a valid timestamp of zeros (`0000-00-00 00:00:00-00`, which results in a out of range error), the lowest date possible according to the docs (`January 1, 4713 BC`) and a blank string (`''`, which just gets a data type mismatch error). There also appears to be no `is_timestamp()` function that I can use to check if the result is not a valid timestamp.

So, the question is, what value is in that empty field that I can check for?

Thanks.

EDIT: The field does not have a default value.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`null` in SQL means 'unknown'.

This means that the result of using any comparison operator, like `=`, with a `null` is also 'unknown'.

To check if a column is `NULL` (or not `NULL`), use the special syntax of `IS NULL` (or `IS NOT NULL`) instead of using `=`.

Applying that to your statement,

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp IS NULL;
```

should work.

Comment: I think he wants where timestamp IS NULL (no not) but yeah, nothing can equal null since null is unknown.

Comment: No, that would just select all timestamps. However you did inadvertently give me the answer: you need to use `timestamp IS NULL`, _not_ `timestamp = NULL`, so thanks.

Comment: This doesn't retrieve the record for me if the timestamp is blank.